# Program crashes when run not from own directory

Tags: c#, xml, path

A basic question:

I have a C# Windows application which runs fine when executed from its own directory, by typing

```
program1.exe
```

but when I execute it from another directory giving full path like

```
d:/progs/myprog/program1.exe
```

it crashes. And I really need to do it this way :)

I suppose it is connected to reading some files by the program which are in the same directory. My suspected line is:

```
using (XmlReader OdczytywaczXML = XmlReader.Create(@"config.xml"))
```

Can it be the problem? I wouldn't like to give full paths to files as I'd like my program to work anywhere just by copying the files.

Oh, and I have no idea how to simulate such condition (running from another directory) while debugging - is it possible?

Comment: It may be because the application doesn't have permissions to run wherever your current directory of your console is executing this. I would suggest trying to run it as admin, and see if that works.

Comment: Did you copy config.xml to the same directory and try to run then, what happened?

Comment: Is this a console application?

Answer (score 5):

You should detect your program location and construct full path to `config.xml` in this case, for example:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location),
    @"config.xml");
```

To simulate condition, go to project properties, page "Debug" and set `Working Directory`.

Comment: +1 for `GetEntryAssembly`; with projects that leverage class libraries doing the work that's a nice touch.

Answer (score 2):

This is surely the problem. You can add directory information on that line. In WinForms you can use `Application.StartupPath` for example.

In General you can use `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`

Comment: Thanks, all answers are probably correct but I tried Application.StartupPath and it worked in my case

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `Working Directory` isn't the same when you just execute it from the command-line. You'll want to safeguard this:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "config.xml");
using (XmlReader OdczytywaczXML = XmlReader.Create(path))
```

The `Location` property will do the following for you:

> Gets the full path or UNC location of the loaded file that contains the manifest.

One thing to note here is that if you added a shortcut to the `Desktop` and set the `Working Directory`, **before changing the code**, you would find the application runs fine. Do that first to verify the fix worked.